# Do followers in Fallout 4 have any perks?

Tags: fallout-4

The player character can select perks that increase weapon damage or add other effects.

Do your followers have any of these?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, companions themselves do not have perks that you can select but they will grant additional perks if you make them happy enough. These perks are as follows:

#### Cait

25% faster AP regeneration if your HP is below 25%

#### Codsworth

+10 Damage Resistance against robot's energy attacks

#### Curie

Heal 100 HP when your HP drops below 10%

#### Deacon

20% more sneak attack and 20% increase in Stealth Boy duration

#### John Hancock

25% more Critical Hit if you have more than 250 RADs

#### MacCready

20% greater chance to hit in VATS

#### Nick Valentine

1 more guess when hacking, additionally, the wait time if you fail a hack is decreased by 50% if Nick is your current companion at the time

#### Paladin Danse

20% more damage against ghouls, super mutants and synths

#### Piper

Double XP for completing speech challenges and discovering new locations on the map

#### Preston Garvey

20% Damage Resistance and 20% more damage when outnumbered

#### Strong

20% more melee damage if your HP is below 25%

#### X6-88

Increases Energy Resistance by 20

#### Dogmeat

Not talking about actual perks in the game but as per the comments there are some unofficial perks relating to Dogmeat, in that he doesn't count as a companion in terms of Lone Wanderer, doesn't talk to you, and doesn't judge your actions. For all intents and purpose, having Dogmeat with you is like not having a companion with you while having a companion with you.

Comment: You forgot Dogmeat:   *Happiness*.  makes you (me, anyway) happy to have a dog around.  Plus *Silence*: companion does 100% less vocalizations during play.    also *Steadfastness*: companion's opinion never goes up or down, so no constraints on your actions.

Comment: I know I can't give followers perk, but some followers in Skyrim had player perks assigned to them which made them stronger to use. Freya had a perk that increased her dual wield attack speed. Will have to wait for the editor to check.

Comment: @CPerkins. Dogmeat's also the only companion you can take with you and still keep the *Lone Wanderer* perk active. He'd be perfect, if he didn't stand in my way all the time. To be fair, though: none of my other companions have ever bothered to *not* stand in my way all the time, so Dogmeat's still the best!

Comment: @CPerkins Dogmeat does bark, but he sometimes discovers something in your target location. For example, I was stuck in the Satellite array location. One bark, follow Dogmeat and wallaa. Location where the Lost Patrol signal was coming from. Plus I like Dogmeat, he looks just like my dog. :-)

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ He barks, but he doesn't *talk*, which is what I meant to say by "100% less vocalizations".   And yes, he's very very useful, and looks like one of my dogs:  I have 2 (soon to be 3) rescued GSDs.  Though the color is off - he's a bit red.  And "Dogmeat" is a disrespectful name, I'd like to be able to change it.  But yeah, from one GSD person to another:  Dogmeat is best companion.

Comment: Since this question scores pretty high on a Goolge search for "Fallout 4 Companion Perks" I think it may be a good idea to add that those perks stay permanently with your character, as stated [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243119/are-companion-perks-in-fallout-4-permanent). I guess your first sentence implies that, but I wasn't completely sure when reading it.

Comment: +1 to @ChristianPoplawski. Also, I'm not sure I'd equate "having Dogmeat" with "not having a companion with you". 'Cause without a companion, I don't have to worry about [this](https://gfycat.com/UniformRealImperialeagle) happening.

Answer (score 1):

Actually yes, they have perks for themselves, mostly sneak 1-4, so they dont blow your cover. You can play around with mods to give them more perks.

Comment: There's already an answer with more detail giving a complete description, so don't be demoralized if this answer isn't accepted =)

Answer (score -4):

I've choked on many running quests with strong. He's hilarious if you choose aggressive/rude dialogue options with people, he will chime in and back you up. His high carry weight is useful too and if you get him his heavy armor and a supersledge, he does great at keeping rushers and hounds off while you snipe. I just wish I could make him take drugs, I'd keep him high 24/7.