# How can I determine my current relationship status?

Tags: fallout-4

Followers in Fallout 4 will grant specific perks ([Do followers in Fallout 4 have any perks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243858/do-followers-in-fallout-4-have-any-perks#243866)), but is it possible to track your progress towards achieving these perks?  In other words, how can I see relationship progress?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to tell directly what your current relationship status is with one or all of your companions.

The only thing you can do is speak to each of your companions and ask them what their thoughts on the relationship are, to which they'll often respond with something that doesn't clearly determine where you are in your relationship but gives you a general overview (their comment will be negative, neutral or positive) and occasionally whether they're thinking about the journey, your actions, or you.

If you're playing on the PC and don't mind using the console you can use the following console command to determine your exact relationship status:

`getav CA_affinity`

This returns the current companion affinity level. Relationship status changes are usually triggered at 250, 500, 750 and 1000, with 1000 being the maximum.

Answer (score 3):

I have the game on PC, this is how I found out.

- Walk up to the companion, following or not.
- Pull up console, click on the companion.
- Type `getav CA_affinity` and hit Enter.

The console will print their relation status level. Getting their relation status to 1000 triggers the "idolized" status where they confront you to talk. The number seems to max out at 1100 (the highest I've seen). I also noticed dogs stay at 0.

Outside console, my only guess is to talk to them and see if "flirt" is available.