# Are there disadvantages to switching companions?

Tags: fallout-4

I got to the highest level of trust of one of my companions. Now I'm curious if there are disadvantages to doing the same with a different companion to get their perk as well.

Do I lose the perk from the first companion? Do I slowly lose karma with them if not traveling with them?

Is there any negative side effect, or should I just run around as a two-faced chameleon gaining the perks from all of them I can?

Comment: almost a duplicate: [Are companion perks in Fallout 4 permanent?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243119/108003)

Comment: @DCShannon, the question itself is about perks, basically. It is a duplicate.

Comment: @icebat, the original question is about perks, and you may interpret that that is the only thing that applies to the answer, but the answer itself can not qualify a question for closure. OP is asking if **any other mechanic applies**, aswell. This includes the listed "slowly lose karma with them if not travelling", and any other potential negative that might be encountered.

Comment: @Timelord64, that's debatable. Karma loss here is in context of losing perks, IMO. The only thing that hints to wider topic is the title, hence the confusion. 
But it's just my subjective opinion anyway, community will decide where this all goes.

Comment: Companion perks are like Pokemon. Gotta get 'em all!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No, ditch 'em.**

Once you get the perk [it is permanent](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/243394/108003), and you won't lose approval for not traveling with them.

Obviously some companions are better than others. So, if you drop Cait, you won't be able to have her pick all the locks anymore, for example. And if you drop your romantic companion, then you won't be able to get Lover's Embrace so easily, but I don't think that's really what you're asking about. To clarify though, you can just switch back later and you won't have lost anything versus when you kicked them to the curb.

Comment: That's what I expected, thanks for the confirmation!